# jQuery of multiple elements not executing, although works on concept

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my concept design the jQuery controlling things like the calendar to appear when the input(s) at the top right are clicked on work fine, however now I'm trying to integrate this into an existing design, all these Javascript elements are not working, although I am using the same code amongst other things which already existed within old design.

I considered it to be simply a compatibility issue of the sidebar calendar, removed it entirely and still nothing. Within the console it defines "Cannot read property 'datetimepicker' of null" for example.

Live URL of the concept (all working elements): http://bit.ly/1m23oXT
Live URL of the non working site: http://bit.ly/1gxgXfx

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo HTTP_HOST; ?>Styles/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
<script src="<?php echo HTTP_HOST; ?>Scripts/jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script>
```

.

```
<div class="header-reservations">
            <div id="usual2" class="usual"> 
              <ul>  
                <li><a href="#tabs2" class="selected">ROOM BOOKINGS</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#tabs3">SPA BOOKINGS</a></li> 
              </ul> 
              <div id="tabs2">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" class="header-form-input" id="datetimepicker" placeholder="21st January" />
                        <select class="header-form-dropdown">
                            <option>1 Night</option>
                            <option>2 Nights</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="header-form-dropdown">
                            <option>1 Adult</option>
                            <option>2 Adults</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" class="header-form-submit blue-btns" value="BOOK" />
                    </form>
                    <span class="clearboth"></span>
              </div> 
              <div id="tabs3">
                    <div class="header-tab-spa">
                        <h3>To Make A Spa Booking, Contact Us <a href="#">Here</a></h3>
                    </div>
                    <span class="clearboth"></span>
              </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

.

```
<!-- Required JS Files -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#usual2 ul").idTabs("tabs2");
    }
</script>

<script src="<?php echo HTTP_HOST; ?>Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is invalid (a parenthesis is missing), you should see an error in the console.

Comment: I see errors but not defining what exactly is the issue, any idea where this parenthesis is missing from?

Comment: You have a parenthesis before `function` in `$(document).ready(function() {`. Close it.

Answer (score 0):

A parenthesis is missing at the end of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#usual2 ul").idTabs("tabs2");
}
```

But such a syntax error should be found using the console, not Stack Overflow. Read [about the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Comment: Changed but with no effect therefore something else causing issue(s) I believe, still trying to remove elements now to try filter out what is preventing things.